# Effecient Feature Searching

Tags: computer-vision, information-retrieval

I have got multiple features(descriptor, vector with elements of natural or real number) from a single image, which need to be searched against many image with multiple features. It is a problem from SLAM, particularly the localization method. What are the SOTA methods for such problems. The naive approach would be to do a k-nn for each feature in the source image and then rank the image from the search space, this is going to be too slow, especially the ranking of the images.